# Grab API Results Every XX Minutes For Local Use

Tags: json, caching

I have a website that consumes a remote API. This api returns a 2mb~ JSON string. My website is mainly JS(Angular). The website that hosts the remote API is sometimes very slow, so I want to store a copy (essentially a cached copy) locally. How could I go about automating this?

Desired Results:

- Every XX minutes/hours MY server consumes the remote API
- MY server stores cached .json file.

So everytime my website pulls the resource, it is pulling locally and I can minimize the load time. Do I need to write up a desktop application to achieve this, or is there an easier method that can be achieved with Node or the like?

**SOLUTION:** I was able to manage this by using a cron-job with the command `wget -O`

Comment: Actually that has not much to do with angularjs, but with nodeJS, PHP or whatever you are using. Maybe change the tag.

Comment: The reason for the tag is my website is mainly aJS. That's all. It has since been removed.

Comment: What is not completely clear to me: Do you require the currently active front-ends (your angular pages) to be notified about the update? Or do you only require the server to update its cached version? Because then you could go for a very simple PHP script that is executed by a cronjob every XX seconds/minutes/whatever that downloads and stores you the cached version - either in a database if you like to have a history or as simple file that can be adressed directly on the webserver.